# Vector Calculus and Support vector machines (SVM)

Tags: svm

In the derivation of the support vector machine solution, one has to differentiate the term $||w||^2$ with respect to $w$ at some point, where $w$ is the normal vector to the hyperplane. The result of this differentiation is $2w$.

Can anyone show me how it comes to $2w$? I am not so clear on how to differentiate a norm with respect to a vector-- I cant see how the result comes to be $2w$.

Comment: Do you know what norm you are working with?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78206/differentiation-in-support-vector-machine

Comment: Can you also tell us where you got the result from?